# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

I have recorded a script and running it. But I'm receiving the following error.

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported in jmeter
```

I'm not sure whether it is script issue or coding issue.
Our application is installed on **HTTPS** but **security certificate not yet installed.**

Could any one please help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It could be one of below

- The endpoint you are requesting is not supported for POST, It may support only GET, Please change the method in Jmeter to GET or the method your url supports
- The endpoint may expect proper CSRF token. It might mismatch with one you recorded. So Please extract CSRF token from previous request's response and use it. You can do via RegEx Extractor in Jmeter.

Comment: I tried using the GET method, but still i'm facing the same error.This time it is HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported. Actually im from testing team.In order to check the code, where should developers need to check(i mean any particular functions etc) in their code?

Comment: Whats the response when you make same request via browser?

Comment: We are able to launch the application with 200 response status in browser.

Comment: Please check if you need to send CSRF token, Its is mostly used in all the POST requests for security reasons. These token are varies for each session/request(based on implementation). When you record the csrf token might be different and when you hit from jmeter it may be different. If this is the case then you need to get the token from previous request's response

Comment: Cookie Data:
XSRF-TOKEN=6532135e-ec63-4003-a748-a62894e15f53; SESSION=4e130461-f4ab-4288-9796-9f85e6443097           We are getting this values in cookies data.This token numbers are not appearing in any service.

Comment: Usually CSRF tokens are kept as hidden field and send as one of the parameter in POST request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113706/discussion-between-selvakumar-ponnusamy-and-bottu-praveen).

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance..I have used reg ex for csrf token. After that it is working

Comment: Good. Edited the answer in detail for others get this information easily rather than going through our discussions in the comment section

Answer (score 0):

JMeter does support POST method so it may be due to:

- Endpoint you're using doesn't support POST method (it expects other method(s) like GET, PUT, DELETE, etc.)
- You're sending not properly configured request.

The most common reason is missing relevant [Content-Type](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) header. You can use [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) in order to send the relevant Content-Type header which is usually `application/json` for REST or `text/xml` or similar for SOAP.

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for more information on API testing using JMeter.

You can also consider the following approach:

1. Use specialized Web Services testing tool like [SoapUI](http://soapui.org/) or [RESTClient](http://restclient.net/) to fire a request
2. Either use aforementioned tool or 3rd-party sniffer like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) to capture the request
3. Configure JMeter to send exactly the same request